# rpm removal failure

Tags: linux, rpm

I'm encountering a problem removing an installed rpm.

```
> rpm -q  my_rpm
my_rpm-3.0.0-27
> rpm -e my_rpm
error: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/__db.000
```

I have also tried to run it as super user. It doesn't work either.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Duplicate: [getting error “Can't create transaction lock” with rpm](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15133/getting-error-cant-create-transaction-lock-with-rpm)

Comment: Did you run ps -ef | grep rpm to see if another rpm instance is running?

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that something else is using the rpm database. If you have a graphical package manager (such as an update manager or a yum gui) open, close it and try again. If you can't find anything, just log out and log back in again.

In any case, `rpm` commands should always be run as `root`, they won't work otherwise.